# Concatenating value into a field without creating duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table per month: zaman_Jan, zaman_Feb, zaman_Mar, zaman_Apr, ..., zaman_Dec.

The columns of such a table are: id, username, d01, d02, d03, d04, ..., d31.

I insert values in a loop, using the following `insert` statement:

```
"INSERT INTO zaman_$month (username, d$day ) 
    VALUES ( '$value1' , '$value2' ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d$day = CONCAT(d$day,'$value2')"
```

where `$value1` is a user name, and `$value2` can be a sequence of values, like:

- Fri May 06 05:10:29 +0000 2016
- Fri May 06 05:10:29 +0000 2016
- Fri May 06 15:08:29 +0000 2016

Then I get the following in the table `zaman_May`:

```
id | username | d06
---+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | value1   | Fri May 06 05:10:29 +0000 2016/Fri May 06 05:10:29 +0000 2016/Fri May 06 15:08:29 +0000 2016
```

but I don't want to have duplicate times. It should be:

```
id | username | d06
---+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | value1   | Fri May 06 05:10:29 +0000 2016/Fri May 06 15:08:29 +0000 2016
```

So I want to add every new value in the field (in the example, in `d06`), but if the value to be merged into an existing row (e.g. field has `15:15:15`, new value also is `15:15:15`), it should skip that value. Only when the value being added does not exist in the target row it should be appended to the existing value (like `15:15:15-16:16:17`).

How can this be made possible?

Comment: Please add an example of what you are trying to do when adding a value that already exists in a row.  Your last paragraph is close to gibberish to me.

Comment: This is a wrong way to design a database. Please read about database normalisation. Don't create a separate table per month, don't create a separate column per day, don't concatenate multiple times as strings in one field.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could get it to work by adding a `where not exist` condition in your `insert` statement, the whole setup of your database is wrong from the start.

You should normalise your database. Don't create a separate table per month, don't create a separate column per day, don't concatenate multiple times as strings in one field. It makes your data manipulation overly complicated.

Create *one* fact table as follows:

```
id | user_id | action_date
---+---------+-------------------------
 1 |     1   | 2016-05-06 05:10:29
 1 |     1   | 2016-05-06 05:08:29
```

If you make those columns part of a unique index, it will not be possible to insert duplicate dates for the same user.

If you have user *names*, then put those in a separate `user` table, where the primary key will be the `user_id`.

When you need data for one month only, just put that in the `where` condition (instead of dynamically picking the right table). The same goes for day of the month: put the day's date in the `where` clause instead of dynamically picking the appropriate day column.

Finally, don't create SQL statements by dynamically inserting `$value1` or `$value2` into it, as this makes your code vulnerable for SQL injection. Use parameterised, prepared statements instead.

Comment: thanks for reply,i will use "https://www.fusioncharts.com/php-charts/" after that,i have to store that datas in database after that i will use these datas for anaylsing and statics, e.g "how many times user loged in a month/day/year? How many times spend user in a day?(max time of a day - min time of a day = total spend time  ) " for this i couldnt change db style do you have any suggestions about that ?

Comment: If you cannot change the database tables, then I would create database views that make the whole thing normalised. However, if you can create views in your database, then you should also be able to improve the existing tables to normalise them. I myself would not go ahead with this solution if all this is not possible, and look for another architecture.